# Escape special characters in echo

Tags: string, unix, text, echo

**http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html** shows a list of special characters. Is there a parameter/option for echo where I can treat everything that comes after the echo as a string?

In python, i could use the `"""..."""` or `'''...'''`.

```
$ python
>>> text = '''#"`\|^!@#@%$#$^%$&%^*()?/\;:$#$@$?$$$!&&'''
>>> print text
#"`\|^!@#@%$#$^%$&%^*()?/\;:$#$@$?$$$!&&
```

**I can do the same in unix's echo with `'''` but not `"""`, why is that so?**

```
$ echo #"`\|^!@#@%$#$^%$&%^*()?/\;:$#$@$?$$$!&&

$ echo '''#"`\|^!@#@%$#$^%$&%^*()?/\;:$#$@$?$$$!&&'''
#"`\|^!@#@%$#$^%$&%^*()?/\;:$#$@$?$$$!&&

$ echo """'''#"`\|^!@#@%$#$^%$&%^*()?/\;:$#$@$?$$$!&&"""
bash: !@#@%$#$^%$: event not found
```

**What happens if i have a string like this?**

```
#"`\|^!@#@%$#$^%'''$&%^*()?/\;:$#$"""@$?$$$!&&
```

How should I echo such a string? (the following command doesn't work)

```
echo '''#"`\|^!@#@%$#$^%'''$&%^*()?/\;:$#$"""@$?$$$!&&'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `printf`:

```
$ printf "%s\n" $'#"`\|^!@#@%$#$^%$&%^*()?/\;:$#$@$?$$$!&&'
#"`\|^!@#@%$#$^%$&%^*()?/\;:$#$@$?$$$!&&
$ printf "%s\n" $'#"`\|^!@#@%$#$^%\'\'\'$&%^*()?/\;:$#$"""@$?$$$!&&'
#"`\|^!@#@%$#$^%'''$&%^*()?/\;:$#$"""@$?$$$!&&
```

You might note that single quotes `'` need to be escaped.

In order to assign the output to a variable:

```
$ foo=$(printf "%s\n" $'#"`\|^!@#@%$#$^%\'\'\'$&%^*()?/\;:$#$"""@$?$$$!&&')
$ echo $foo
#"`\|^!@#@%$#$^%'''$&%^*()?/\;:$#$"""@$?$$$!&&
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of your shell (bash), which [expands/interprets double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html).
This does not apply for single quotes.
For details, please have a look at [Bash - Shell Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions).

For the `echo` command there is the `-e` option which enables interpretation of backslash escapes - which might help.